# Update a ListSelect in Vaadin 7

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I need to update the list of a **ListSelect** after i click in one button but i dont know how to

Here is my code:

**Create List Method**

```
private void createListPanel() {
        VerticalLayout listPanel = new VerticalLayout();
        listPanel.setWidth(100f, Unit.PERCENTAGE);

        queryList= new ListSelect("List Of Querys", getQueryList());
        queryList.setWidth(100f, Unit.PERCENTAGE);

        queryList.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);

        queryList.addValueChangeListener(event -> {

            selectedQuery = (String) (queryList.getValue());
            String retrievedQuery = repository.getRawQuery(selectedQuery);

        });

        listPanel.addComponent(queryList);
        panelSuperior.addComponent(listPanel);
    }
```

**getQueryList()**

```
private List<String> getQueryList() {
    return repository.getQueryNames();
}
```

**Create Button Method**

```
private void CreateButton() {
    Button buttonRefresh= new Button("Refresh");

    buttonRefresh.addClickListener((Button.ClickEvent e) -> {
        // i tried this
        queryList.setContainerDataSource((Container) getQueryList());
    });

    buttonPanel.addComponent(button);

}
```

I tried this line at CreateButton() method:

```
queryList.setContainerDataSource((Container) getQueryList())
```

but i get a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.vaadin.data.Container
```

because this method need a **Container Object**

I was searching in the Vaadin javadoc but I am not able to find a method to set or update the list of the ListSelect

**Vaadin Javadoc:** [Vaadin Javadoc 7.7.9 ListSelect](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/ListSelect.html)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are `listaConsultas` and `queryList` the same thing? Same question for `obtenerNombresLista` and `getQueryList`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i forgot to change this names when i was translating, i edited my answer whit the correct names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward way is to remove all items from an underlying container and add new items afterward:

```
Container container = queryList.getContainerDataSource();
container.removAllItems();
List<String> queries = getQueryList();
for(String query : queries) {
    container.addItem(query);
}
```

[`ListSelect(String caption, Collection<?> options)`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractSelect.html#AbstractSelect-java.lang.String-java.util.Collection-) constructor creates an [`IndexedContainer`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/IndexedContainer.html) and populates it with items from your collection.

Another option is to bind `ListSelect` to a container which could possibly enable it to track changes automatically. For more on this, see ["Collecting Items in Containers"](https://vaadin.com/docs7/-/part7/framework/datamodel/datamodel-container.html) topic from Vaadin docs.